# Handler onTap Custom Button and button

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-layout

I have a customButton and I would like to pass a VoidCallback function to it with the validation of my form

```
 CustomButtonWidget(
                      text: 'Cadastrar',
                       callback: () async {
                       final FormState form = formKey.currentState;
                        if (form.validate()) {
                        form.save();
                        controller.cadastrar();
                        } else {
                        //snackbar
                        print('erro ao entrar');
                        }
                        }),
```

My Custom ButtonClass

```
    class CustomButtonWidget extends Container {
  final String text;
  final VoidCallback callback;
  CustomButtonWidget({@required this.text, this.callback,});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 0.5,
      height: 50,
      child: RaisedButton(
        autofocus: false,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
        ),
          onPressed: this.callback,
          child: Text(
            this.text,
            style: textButton,
          ),
          color: Colors.green),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm receveid this error

```
Handler: "onTap"
I/flutter (29423): Recognizer:
I/flutter (29423):   TapGestureRecognizer#9b3b5
I/flutter (29423): ═════════════════════════════════════════
```

or this

```
I/flutter (29423): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
I/flutter (29423): The method 'call' was called on null.
I/flutter (29423): Receiver: null
I/flutter (29423): Tried calling: call()
I/flutter (29423):
```

I tried everything () => callback, or async, I don’t know what to do anymore

Comment: The code you provided works fine, the problem is inside the callback function, can you provide the code of the 'call' method and where it is being called?

Comment: Tanks for attention, would be the function I'm calling?

`  cadastrar(){
    this.isEmpresa ? this.user.tipo = '1' : this.user.tipo = '2';
    repository.cadastro(this.user); `

Comment: I don't understand I have a project that works exactly like this https://github.com/kauemurakami/client-flutter-get/blob/master/lib/pages/client/client.dart, when declaring variables inside the callback nothing works, even if the controller method of the error

Comment: Trying to reproduce i couldn't achieve the same error, are you sure that all the variables are initialized?

Comment: For example if i didn't instantiate the controller, the 'cadastrar' method would be called on null.

Comment: I will leave the public code on github for a few moments, I hope it can help me, as I said, I have done this before, and I am not understanding this error, I am all day in it the project is too advanced to be redone. Here is the project link, https://github.com/kauemurakami/connect/tree/master/lib/app/modules/cadastro, the variables are initialized as they are all attributes of my user

Comment: this module cause error

Comment: Yes, i'm instance the controller in my cadastro_page.dart, with Get.put(CadastroController(repository: repository)); and the controller contain a function of test with print('hello') and work 
 CustomButtonWidget(
                              text: 'aaaa',
                              callback: () async => controller.c(),
                            ),

Comment: The problem is not there, see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already tried your repository, and I found the problem was not within `CustomButtonWidget`.

It was actually from this line in *lib/app/modules/cadastro/cadastro_page.dart*:

```
CustomTextFormField(
  onSaved: (value) => controller.onSavedName(value),
  // <<< ------ this line
  action: TextInputAction.next,
  text: 'Nome',
),
```

As defined in `CustomTextFormField`, in *lib/app/widgets/custom_textff_widget.dart*,  it is **mandatory** to add

```
onChanged : (value) => {}
```

and

```
validator : (value) => {}
```

As soon as you changed to this lines

```
CustomTextFormField(
  onSaved: (value) => controller.onSavedName(value),
    onChanged: (value) =>
        controller.onChangeName(value),
    validator: (value) =>
        controller.nameValidate(value),
  action: TextInputAction.next,
  text: 'Nome',
),
```

the problem will be solved. Don't forget to add onChangeName and nameValidate on your controller

Here is the screenshot of final result

[image]

Comment: thanks, on my custom button when trying to set a default value of null for the functions, the message of unnecessary code was displayed, I thought it would be null, in case the error is due to my component needing this in all calls? wouldn't it be possible to define some that i don't need validation or is it an exclusive form requirement for its validation?
and thanks again for your attention

Comment: I still don't get it. What did you mean by ' set a default value of null for the functions ' ? which Functions are we discussing here, are those one these 'emailValidate', 'telefoneValidate' ? If no validation needed when there is no value inputted inside the inputbox, you can use this https://gist.github.com/ejabu/900c08706f69374b496895103cb154c1